# Scheduled Remote Desktop Manager With Credentials

Tags: terminal, scheduled

I've a lot of servers with Windows Server and remote desktop enabled. For a problem with the windows domain, servers occasionally not perform the login process. So to solve this problem, I need a software or script that allows me to schedule logins on each server and if one fails to send me an email to let me know. Someone knows a software or script to perform this task? Thank you.

Comment: What you are asking for is a band-aid.  You need to fix the root cause of why servers occasionally aren't allowing logins to occur.

Comment: we are working to solve the problem. Meanwhile servers need to know that we are getting this error because errors are random and occur every few days and only on some servers and not others

Answer (score 1):

Nagios has a plugin for this. Since you haven't told us what monitoring system you use (if any), I'm figuring you're wide open for suggestions.

http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Network-Protocols/RDP